# exporting flash CS6 action script 3.0 to .mov

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, export, adobe, flash-cs6

Hi I am trying to export a flash file that used to contain action script (which is now removed form the .fla file) however the document used to create the file was Action Script 3.0. I am trying to export this file as a .mov but when I attempt an export on flash I get a message in Output:

Warning: No libraries were linked as Runtime Shared Libraries (RSLs) because of your publish settings: Exporting QuickTime Movie

I also get a pop up message saying that: The export operation failed because it ran out of memory.

I have tried exporting the .fla file in Adobe Media Encoder which also doesn't work as the: File format is not supported..

Does anyone understand what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

"Out of memory" error has occurs when compile didn't know your finish time. You can simply do following instructions :

> File -> Export -> Export Movie

After that you can check **"after time elapsed"** tick. But you have to input your finish time manually.

a few months ago i got same error. I did it this way and it worked properly.

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me! my animation is 122 seconds (2.03minutes) i typed in 0:2:1 and the same occurred again..

Comment: Well, then click file/publish settings/flash/script settings/library paths/default linkage, select merged into code and click ok.  republish and retest.